Given a predictor $x$. under what circumstance would you have high $R^2$ but low $\beta$
Assume I have a time series $y$ and a predictor $x$. Let's say they are both centered at zero.
$$R^2 = 1 - \frac{ \sum (y_i - x_i)^2 }{\sum y_i^2}$$
Now I run a new regression $y \sim \beta x$, in an attempt to "rescale" my predictor.
$\beta = \frac{\operatorname{cov}(x,y)}{\operatorname{var}(x)} = \frac{\sum x_i y_i}{\sum x_i^2}$
I want to find a relationship between $\beta$ and $R^2$ (note this $R^2$ is what I computed above $R^2 = 1 - \frac{ \sum (y_i - x_i)^2 }{\sum y_i^2}$, not $R^2$ of my new regression that produced $\beta$, $x$ is already a predictor )
My hypothesis is that $R^2$ is maximized when $\beta = 1$. Because that means my predictor $x$ is "well-scaled". But I have trouble proving it... if that's not true, why would $R^2$ not maximize when my predictor is "best scaled"?
$$\sum x_i y_i = \beta \sum x_i^2,$$
plug into
\begin{align}
R^2 & = 1 - \frac{ \sum (y_i - x_i)^2 }{\sum y_i^2} \\[6pt] & = 1 - \frac{ \sum x_i^2 - 2\sum x_i y_i + \sum y_i^2 }{\sum y_i^2} \\[6pt] & = \frac{ 2 \sum x_i y_i - \sum x_i^2 }{\sum y^2_i} = (2\beta-1) \frac{ \sum x_i^2 }{ \sum y_i^2}.
\end{align}
Nothing suggests that $R^2$ is maximized when $\beta = 1$ but as I mentioned, not sure why $R^2$ not maximize when my predictor is "best scaled"?

Let's consider a regression relationship between, say, driving time $y$ and distance travelled $x$:
$$y = x\beta + e$$
$x$ is denominated in kilometers, just for fun.  Now, let's rescale $x$, so that it is denominated in centimeters.  What is the new $\beta$, label it $\beta'$?  As all the $x$-values are multiplied by $100,000$, clearly $\beta' = \beta / 100,000$.
We can continue this rescaling of $x$ in any direction, making $\beta$ as large or small as we want.  The underlying model, of course, has not changed, just the units of measurement of $x$ - implying that $R^2$ hasn't changed either.   So... there is no relationship between $\beta$ and $R^2$.

I tried to stress in my question. The $R^2$ in question is not the $R^2$ from the new regression that produced $\beta$. It's from directly compute $R^2 = 1 - \frac{ \sum (y_i - x_i)^2 }{\sum y_i^2}$. $x$ itself is already a predictor

Sure, but you've never specified what the true value of $\beta$ is.  If you are saying that the true value of $\beta = 1$, a) you should put that in the question, and b) of course that will be the value that maximizes $R^2$. My point is that, by rescaling $x$, any value of $\beta$ can be the value that maximizes $R^2$, not just $1$.

I am trying to prove that will really maximize $R^2$ though.. I am not sure why the "of course" part is obvious

To clarify a point - in any given sample, it's extremely unlikely that the optimal $\hat{\beta} = 1$, but that's not what you're asking, right?  You're asking what maximizes $R^2$ for the population?

Suggest clarifying what you denote by β since you and the OP seem to be using it to indicate the UNstandardized regression coefficient.  What then is b?  And what then is the standardized coefficient?

@rolando2 - this post has nothing to do with standardization, as far as I can tell.

The OP says "My hypothesis is that R2 is maximized when β=1."  Seems they are talking about a standardized coefficient.

I think I understood my confusion. My question was not well asked.

basically if we are comparing two predictors $x_1$ and $x_2$, obviously even if one is "well-scaled", it doesn't mean one is better than another. But for the same scaler, better scaled is always better. I think that's my confusion.

I think my answer shows that "well-scaled" is a meaningless concept in this context; you get the same accuracy regardless of scale (except for computational reasons, i.e., doing the calculation on a machine with finite-precision) by changing the value of $\beta$ to reverse the rescaling of $x$.
